# Issue implementing child class method

Tags: .net, ajax, api, odata, odatacontroller

So I'm having a bit of a problem... the thing is that I have a base class that has implementation for all GET/POST/PUT/DELETE and it's a Generic class so basically whatever I Entity I update passes through there and then I have a class for my entities that implements that class...

```
public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] TKey key)
```

The thing is that for one of the Entities I want to implement additional logic before updating the database so I thought I just do it on the child class and then after that new logic I call the base class method and that should do the trick so I created an overloaded method

```
public override Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(int key){
     //NEW LOGIC
     return base.Put(key);
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that when I do the request from the Client, if I don't have this new method implemented it works fine and calls the base clase method and the Entity is updated but after I added this, using exactly the same ajax request it returns a 400 response... Can anyone help me out figuring out what's going on? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I think this is inherently wrong and goes against Odataprotocol. `PUT` must have model as parameter. Or delta. You can't put simple primitive type. So, your override method hides the base one but Odata route builder can't find it. hence 400

Answer (score 0):

Here is extract from the [document](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part1-protocol.html)

> 1.4.3 Update an Entity
>    . . . 
>   Services MAY additionally support PUT, but should be aware of the potential for data-loss in round-tripping properties that the client may not know about in advance, such as open or added properties, or properties not specified in metadata. **Services that support PUT MUST replace all values of structural properties with those specified in the request body**.  . . .

I guarantee you that OData can't resolve the route you supplied because it is looking for `PUT` with model as parameter and then also, you can have key. Hence, you get error #400.

I don't know, even, if using `ODataRouteAttribute` will help